# CakePHP one page not using theme

Tags: cakephp, themes

I have a CakePHP Application which uses a theme, however I would like to set one page (login) that is a totally different design.

Users will hit this page first and be required to login, the login page needs to use css img js etc from the theme though.

How can I achieve this, im new to CakePHP and struggling to find the solution

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple layout-files (`App/View/Layout`).
The layout-file is automatic default (`App/View/Layout/default.ctp`).
You can change the layout-file in your controller with: `$this->layout = "custom";`.
Create the file `custom.ctp` in `App/View/Layout/`.

Good luck!

**Edit**: For mor info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Comment: @StevenMarks Great! Good luck with this awesome lovely framework ;)